# Cannot have mTLS authentification working with openssl

Tags: ssl, openssl

I have created a CA certificate (ca.crt) that I used to sign a server certificate (server.crt) and a client one (client.crt).

I'm testing the mutual authentication but do not get what I'm expecting.

I'm running the server with:

```
$ openssl s_server -accept 9003 -CAfile ca.crt -cert server.crt -key server.key -Verify 10 -state -msg
```

and the client:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect localhost:9003 -key client.key -cert client.crt -CAfile ca.crt -state -tlsextdebug -verify 10
verify depth is 10
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
depth=1 C = FR, ...
verify return:1
depth=0 C = FR, ...
verify return:1
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server key exchange A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate request A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server done A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client certificate A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client key exchange A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write certificate verify A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write finished A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 flush data
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server session ticket A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read finished A
```

The communication is established and I can send text to the server.

But, if I run the client using dummy KO-client.crt / KO-client.key not signed by the known CA, the communication is also fine...

```
$ openssl s_client -connect localhost:9003 -key KO-client.key -cert KO-client.crt -CAfile ca.crt -state -tlsextdebug -quiet -verify 10
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
depth=1 C = FR, ...
verify return:1
depth=0 C = FR, ...
verify return:1
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server key exchange A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate request A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server done A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client certificate A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client key exchange A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write certificate verify A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write finished A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 flush data
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server session ticket A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read finished A
```

I cannot figure out what I'm missing here.

Comment: Please have a look at the output of the server. `s_server` and `s_client` don't stop if they cannot verify a certificate, they just print that the verification failed but continue.

Comment: Thanks, can you make it as an the answer ?

Comment: In order to make this a good answer I would need the output from your server which shows the actual result of the verification and where one could see that it succeeds in verifying the client certificate in one case and fails but continues in the second case. Only, no output of the server is provided.